# Best way to handle multilanguage support?

Tags: c#, internationalization

I've been searching on SO on how to do i18n support on my little application...

I know that Microsoft offers 'culture' classes, but you have to re-compile your application to include any new string you add. So, all I'm trying to do is to put all my strings in a external file and offers users the choice to translate the app without the need to recompile.

Is there an easy way to handle this ? Use XML, or INI-like ? any Tutorial available ?
P.S: Trying to do this on C#... Don't bother if other languages

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice blog post from Scott Hanselman which contains several good resources:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETInternationalizationGlobalizationAndLocalizationWhew.aspx

Generally speaking I can say that you will want to keep your resources external to your binaries (using something like a .resource file), which will allow you to add/edit resources without a recompile.  I've not done much myself, so I'm a bit rusty on the whole thing.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you include a new string in your app, you have to recompile it anyway, do you not?

if you add languages often, resource files and/or satellite DLLs are probably your best bet

failing that, you can write your own provider. Here are some links I found useful, your mileage may vary:

http://en.csharp-online.net/Localization_Like_the_Pros

http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=211

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DeclarativeGlobalization.aspx

[MS toolkit for web pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479334.aspx)

[CE solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/locale/celocalization.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I mean.. If you change translation for a string.

Comment: [@Black Horus]: in that case external resource files are probably your best best, they can be compiled separately